# Configuring AWS S3 as an image server

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm looking to use AWS S3 as an image server for my java application. At any point in time we could be hosting over a million images, so my question is along the lines of storing the images.

1. I'm my current application, I store them in nested directories

   Example

   ```
   domain.com/63/45/1d/d435.jpg
   ```

   So should I continue to store images in directories like that? or is it better to store them in the root folder? I'm not sure how AWS scales it's S3 instances, so I want to be sure I do it correctly.
2. What is a bucket? is a bucket just the storage instance in my S3 instance?
3. What is the key being passed into `PutObjectRequest`? I'm not sure if this is how you provide the directories assuming credentials are passed into AmazonS3Client.
4. When reading from the s3 instance, is it best to point a `cname` record such as `images.domain.com` to my S3 instance and pull the images directly? If so, would you need to configure the S3 instance as static web hosting?

Answer (score 3):

1. Unless you're going to be continuously uploading in excess of 50 to 100 images per second into S3, [it doesn't really matter](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/03/amazon-s3-performance-tips-tricks-seattle-hiring-event.html).  S3 doesn't store your files in "folders" but it does use the slashes to provide the visual equivalent of "folders" when you browse in the console, and you can use the slashes as prefix delimiters when programmatically fetching lists of objects.  There is no performance benefit either way, whether you store all your files in the root or split them out with slashes in the paths.  The only potential impact of the file naming is when you are uploading files at an extremely high rate, and the first few bytes of the file names are all identical... S3 cam throttle you.  But it's unlikely that you will encounter this.  If you do, back off and retry automatically, or split up your workload so you're not uploading consecutively-named files in such a short time window.
2. S3 does not use the term "instance."  Or "files" for that matter.  "Files" are called "objects" and "objects" are stored in "buckets," with each one having a "key" (the full path+filename)  "images.example.com" might be what you call your images bucket and "63/45/1d/d435.jpg" would be the key of a file accessed via  images.example.com/63/45/1d/d435.jpg.
3. The "key" is the "file name" of the "object".  There are no actual directories, every object is identified by its "key" -- which looks like /path/to/file/and/filename.ext... which means you don't have to do anything to "create" those directories.  They magically appear because there are files with those prefixes, and disappear when (if) you delete the files.
4. There is no S3 "instance" that is yours.  You don't get a "virtual machine" when you use S3, your requests are served by the massive, scalable, distributed entity that is S3, and it's a system that's far more scalable than you can probably imagine, considering that it serves in excess of a million requests per second, every second, all day, every day.  Configure the bucket for static web site hosting, and point a CNAME to the bucket's web site endpoint, as displayed in the console, OR use an Alias record if you are using Route 53 for your DNS.